# Why doesn't Turtle work in Linux command line, but from IDLE?

Tags: python, linux, python-idle, turtle-graphics

I was at a Python group session. On the laptop I was on with Linux installed, I executed the following code (from the book Teach Your Children Python) via the terminal with the usual command:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Pen()
t.speed(0)
turtle.onscreenclick(t.setpos)
```

> Python3.4 TurtleDraw.py

It's supposed to bring up a window that can take mouse cursor input.  Instead, the window appears and disappears right away. Another person tried the similar thing on his MacBook with the same results. However, he ran the same code through a version of IDLE, and it did work as intended.

Is there something in IDLE that automatically integrates with that Turtle window? I take it environment variables may need to be set if I wanted this to work correctly via a Unix command line to run it?

Answer (score 4):

At a command line `python xyz.py`, tells Python to execute the program and when it is done, quit and clean up.  In the case of your `turtledraw.py`, it deletes the turtle screen, as you observed.  To keep the screen visible, you must keep the program from exiting.  One way<sup>[1]</sup> to do this is with the `-i` option: `python -i xyz.py`.  This means: "when reaching the end of the program, switch to 'interactive mode' instead of exiting".  One use for this is for debugging, by examining the values of global variables.  Another is to interactive with a graphics screen.  Whether it does or not, the book *should* tell you to use `-i` when running from the console.

When you edit `xyz.py` in IDLE and run it, IDLE simulates `python -i xyz.py`: after running `xyz.py`, it leaves it *open* for introspection or interaction.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Another way sometimes given to prevent exit is to put an `input()` statement at the end of the program, but this might not work with a GUI program.

EDIT: I tested that `-i` works for `TestDraw.py` on Win10 with Python 3.5.0.

Comment: The reason tkinter programs do not similarly disappear is that they typically end with a mainloop() call that starts an event loop that responds to input events.  The TurtleDraw.py program sets some internal variables but apparently does not cause turtle to call mainloop() or do anything similar.

Comment: I don't have the book with me, but the book does instruct its readers to get set up with IDLE, so it's kind of a moot scenario.  Also, being it is a beginner's book for children, I wouldn't be willing to bet real money that it's in there.  However, I am curious none of the less, and want to go through that chapter again just to double check for any mention of the -i option